# How to parse TRUE and FALSE value into string using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file. One of the columns is type `General`. Values in this column have formats like `10cm`, `0`, `1`, `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Now I'm using Pandas to parse the Excel file into a dataframe and then save them in a table in SQLite. I want the values in this column keep its own format.

I have used `xl=pd.ExcelFile()` to read the file and `xl.parse()` to read the data. But the `FALSE` value in the column become `0`, which confuses me with real `0` value. The code line is

```
df=xl.parse(sheet_name=sheet,names=columns,skiprows=2)
```

where the sheet is a given sheetname and columns is a list of column names.

Could someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it-

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Practice\\Book1.xlsx',header=0,converters={'General':str})
df
```

Output

General
10cm
0
1
True
False

[image]

Comment: That's frustrating. It works for you but not for me. I also used Jupyter to test.

Comment: I would suggest you to check your excel file format, as It works in all IDE. I checked in Spyder too.

Comment: I tried again with dummy data in a new excel file. Still it does not work. FALSE becomes False and TRUE becomes 1.

Comment: I found the solution. I miss understood the parameter converts, now I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it's type using the `dtype` parameter. Please try with:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file_path',sheet_name=sheet,skiprows=2,dtype={'General':object})
```

Comment: The issue remains the same and now even True becomes 1. After reading the excel file I need to export into a table in SQLite. What I see now in the column is that True is 1 and False is 0. SqLitebrowser is the GUI I am using to view tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping `TRUE` and `FALSE` to string object before you parse to excel like this

```
pd['General'] = pd['General'].map({True: 'True', False: 'False'})
```

Or you can use `replace` with the same impact

```
pd['General'] = pd['General'].replace({True: 'True', False: 'False'})
```